# How to replace all numbers of exactly 8 characters in length eg 12345678

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, replace, numbers

I've done a good bit of searching all over so don't berate me yet.

I have a column with string values showing the name of shows.

Eg:

```
[Titles]
World Cup 2014
Family Guy
UFC Fight Night
9pm News and Weather
2014 Media Awards
Homeland 25242324
Simpsons 25242314
Shameless
Soccer Night 45342324 International
Rugby Live 45342324 HTML5
```

I wish to use a select statement to strip out the numbers where the numbers are exactly 8 characters in length.

I have only read access so cannot create functions and I'm using SQL Server 2005.

Comment: Just to make sure, you are trying to do this with SQL on the database itself?  You could consider using Regexes client-side to strip out the parts of the string you don't need.

Comment: What have you tried? BTW, in the examples you posted there are no values where the number sequence is 8. The longest one there is 7. ;)

Comment: You'll end up creating a scalar function that parses the strings character-by-character if you keep it in SQL.

Comment: Sorry, I have now amended the example to include 8 digit numbers, duh. :)

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of split functions that can be found around the internet. My personal preference is the one created by Jeff Moden and enhanced by the community over the last few years. You can find his article here, http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/. Make sure you look at the comments...there are a few hundred at the time of this posting. Here is the code for that splitter.

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[DelimitedSplit8K]
--===== Define I/O parameters
        (@pString VARCHAR(8000), @pDelimiter CHAR(1))
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING AS
 RETURN
--===== "Inline" CTE Driven "Tally Table" produces values from 0 up to 10,000...
     -- enough to cover VARCHAR(8000)
  WITH E1(N) AS (
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL 
                 SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 1
                ),                          --10E+1 or 10 rows
       E2(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E1 a, E1 b), --10E+2 or 100 rows
       E4(N) AS (SELECT 1 FROM E2 a, E2 b), --10E+4 or 10,000 rows max
 cteTally(N) AS (--==== This provides the "zero base" and limits the number of rows right up front
                     -- for both a performance gain and prevention of accidental "overruns"
                 SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                 SELECT TOP (DATALENGTH(ISNULL(@pString,1))) ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) FROM E4
                ),
cteStart(N1) AS (--==== This returns N+1 (starting position of each "element" just once for each delimiter)
                 SELECT t.N+1
                   FROM cteTally t
                  WHERE (SUBSTRING(@pString,t.N,1) = @pDelimiter OR t.N = 0) 
                )
--===== Do the actual split. The ISNULL/NULLIF combo handles the length for the final element when no delimiter is found.
 SELECT ItemNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY s.N1),
        Item       = SUBSTRING(@pString,s.N1,ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(@pDelimiter,@pString,s.N1),0)-s.N1,8000))
   FROM cteStart s
;
```

No matter which splitter you use (as long as it is a table valued function) it can work just like this.

```
if OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Something') is not null
    drop table #Something;

create table #Something
(
    SomeValue varchar(100)
);

insert #Something
select 'World Cup 2014' union all
select 'Family Guy' union all
select 'UFC Fight Night' union all
select '9pm News and Weather' union all
select '2014 Media Awards' union all
select 'Homeland 2524232' union all
select 'Simpsons 2524231' union all
select 'Shameless' union all
select 'Soccer Night 4534232 International' union all
select 'Rugby Live 4534232 HTML5';

with ParsedData as
(
    select * 
    from #Something s
    cross apply dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(s.SomeValue, ' ')
    where Item not like '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
)

select distinct
    Stuff((SELECT ' ' + Item
              FROM ParsedData p2
              WHERE  p1.SomeValue = p2.SomeValue
              ORDER  BY p1.ItemNumber --The split function keeps track of the order for us already
              FOR XML PATH('')), 1, 1, ' ') as Details
from ParsedData p1
```

Answer (score -1):

```
create table #tmp(myString varchar(255))
insert into #tmp
values('Soccer Night 45342327 International'),('9pm News and Weather')



    Select newstring = case when  patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',mystring) > 0 then
        left(mystring, patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',mystring) - 1) 
        + substring(mystring,patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',mystring) + 8,9999)
        else mystring end
        from #tmp
    drop table #tmp
```

Comment: This works fine until there are 2 sets of numbers that need to be removed.

Comment: I cant upvote as im noob but this looks good, so give the lad some upvote;). My dataset doesnt contain instances where there are two sets of numbers sean.